# Possible with carrierwave in Rails to upload photo to S3 based off of remote url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, file-upload, amazon-s3, carrierwave

In a Rails application that has a Resource with a photo object as a property through carrierwave which uploads to S3, I want to be able to create an object through ActiveRecord like

```
object = Object.create(title: "Blah blah", photo: "www.remoteurl.com/photo.jpg")
object.save!
```

Is this possible to do so that carrierwave will take the URL provided to the field bound to carrierwave, download the image, and upload it to S3 like it normally does?

As of now, when looking at the params hash of a new resource created, the photo field comes in the form of an Uploader object with UploadedFile attached. If carrierwave doesn't provide this functionality, is it possible to create an UploadedFile object based off the remote url, attach it to the appropriate field and use it to construct the resource object?

I know that carrierwave provides a means of uploading a file from URL through a view, but my objective is to construct objects on the server programmatically with a remote URL rather than through a view.

Answer (score 1):

You can successfully attach a remote photo to your model attribute thats mounted to carrierwave by

```
object = Object.create

object.remote_(your property here)_url = "www.example.com/photo.jpg"
```

and then

```
object.(your property here)
```

will return the uploaded photo object created based off the remote URL